# Using multiple Django forms in single View which are dependent through OnetoOneField/ForeignKey

Tags: django, forms, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I have two models:-

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    is_customer = models.BooleanField('customer status',default=False)
    is_manager = models.BooleanField('manager status',default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username

class Customer(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User,on_delete=models.PROTECT,primary_key=True,related_name="customers")
    full_name = models.CharField(max_length=264,)
    roll_no = models.IntegerField()
    mobile_no = models.IntegerField()
    hostel = models.CharField(max_length=264)
    room_no = models.CharField(max_length=264,)
```

Here Customer's user object is dependent on the User model.

forms.py:-

```
class UserCreateForm(UserCreationForm):
    class Meta:
        fields =('username','email','password1','password2')
        model = User

    def __str__(self,*args,**kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args,**kwargs)
        self.fields["username"].label ="Display name"
        self.fields["email"].label = "Email address"


class CustomerForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Customer
        fields = ['full_name','roll_no','hostel']
```

What I want is to take Customer's details along with User details.
So, How can I use these **two models in one View** (class-based views will be preferred) and create a single form in the Html file?
Please explain the code for views.py and for related Html file.